# The "tick" mark of dropzone is not showing?

Tags: jquery, node.js, dropzone.js

I have been using dropzone to upload the image file on my localhost. Everything is working fine, file is being uploaded and saved, however, the progress bar is not replaced by the tick mark. It stays there.
Here is a screenshot
[image: This is what being shown]

What could be the problem in this case, here is my dropzone code

```
 Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "userPhoto", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 20, // MB
        maxFiles: 1,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg",
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one',
        accept: function (file, done) {
           done();
        },

    };
```

Comment: Which version using?

Comment: latest one...downloaded from site itself

Comment: https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/jobs/49184863/artifacts/file/dist/dropzone.js

Comment: My guess is `css` conflict, like `z-index` or etc for `img` tag,  comment all your `css` file except dropzone, see it work or not

Comment: okie checking it

Comment: Nope, still the problem persists. Is it something related to the response code sent by server

Comment: I don't think so, more like css or js issue.unless uploading faild, any error in console? or errolog

Comment: No nothing, no error of such sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `res.end('File have been uploded')` at the end of your route. When using dropzone, it doesn't acknowledge that the file has been uploaded if res.end is not fired. Hence the animation was not working