# Why dropzone is not refreshing the page after upload?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dropzone.js

I have been working with file upload and wanting to refresh the page when the file upload with dropzone is completed. However, i am trying but i am out of luck
Here is my dropzone html.

```
 <form method='post' action='/events/{{eventName}}/upload' enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone">

            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            </div>

        </form>
```

My drop file with all the configurations

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
paramName: "userPhoto", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 20, // MB
maxFiles: 1,
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg",
dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one',
init: function () {
    // Set up any event handlers
    this.on("complete", function (file) {
        if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
}};
```

And finally my server file which handles upload:

```
app.post('/events/:event/upload', upload, function (req, res) {
var fb_id = req.user.id;
var email = req.user._json.email;
var random = req.rand;
var place = req.params.event;

console.log(fb_id);

var query = {
    'Fbid': fb_id
}



var voteDb = new likeImformation({
    'Fbid': fb_id,
    'imageId': random,
    "email": email,
    'event': place
})


jimp.read('./uploads/Big/' + random + req.ext, function (err, lenna) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lenna.quality(80)
        .scaleToFit(1024, 1024)
        .write('./uploads/Big/' + random + req.ext); // save
});

jimp.read('./uploads/Big/' + random + req.ext, function (err, lenna) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lenna.cover(280, 320) // resize
        .quality(80) // set JPEG qualit
        .exifRotate()
        .write('./uploads/Small/' + random + req.ext); // save



    likeImformation.find(query).find(function (err, data_of_user) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data_of_user.length; i++) {
            if (data_of_user[i].event === place) {
                count++;
            }
        }


        if (count < 10) {
            console.log(data_of_user.length);
            voteDb.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("save");
                }
            })
        }
    })


});
```

});

Why is the page not being reloaded?

Comment: Are other options apply to the dropzone? such as whitelist? There might be problems with assigning the options list

Comment: Also make sure that this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0 is true by console.log'ing this

Comment: see this question of mine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093119/the-tick-mark-of-dropzone-is-not-showing

Comment: I console logged it....this.on('complete') is not firing

Comment: I think, file is being uploaded to server but the dropzone is not knowing that have been uploded